# Applying Filters on images for search function using options

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hi I am trying to write a code that will allow me to set options for specific fields and display the image that meets the requirements of the filters that have been applied once the search button has been clicked.

This is my code so far: As you can see in the snippet below is that I am not sure how to add specific categories to these images and then search them. For example how would I add ( adventure, rating of 8+ and a year of publish to the book like of pi. And then set all the options to as desired and then when I click search only show up with the books which contain the same categories placed on them.

```css
  .review-img {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 160px; // height
  //width: 30%; // width
  }

  #searchfield {
  background-color:red;
  height:150px;
  margin-top:0px;
  text-align: center;

  }

 #main-search-fields {
 padding-top: 66px;
 background-color:red;
 }

 .selects-container {
  display: inline-block;

 }
```

```html
    <body>
   <div id ="searchfield">
   <div id="main-search-fields">
   <div class="selects-container">
  <p>Genre:</p>
  <select name="genre">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="action">Action</option>
  <option value="adventure">Adventure</option>
  <option value="animation">Animation</option>
  <option value="biography">Biography</option>
  <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
  <option value="crime">Crime</option>
  <option value="documentary">Documentary</option>

  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects-container">
  <p>Rating:</p>
  <select name="rating">
  <option value="0">All</option>
  <option value="9">9+</option>
  <option value="8">8+</option>
  <option value="7">7+</option>
  <option value="6">6+</option>
  <option value="5">5+</option>
  <option value="4">4+</option>
  <option value="3">3+</option>
  <option value="2">2+</option>
  <option value="1">1+</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selects-container selects-container-last">
  <p>Order By:</p>
  <select name="order_by">
  <option value="latest">Latest</option>
  <option value="oldest">Oldest</option>
  <option value="year">Year</option>
  <option value="rating">Rating</option>
  <option value="likes">Likes</option>
  <option value="alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" id="search" value="search"  />
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <section class='images'>
<img class="review-img" id="lifeofpi" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51atapp7YTL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="lifeofpi"></img>
<img class="review-img" id="kiterunner" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51MtGFNeYjL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="kiterunner"></img>    
<img class="review-img" id="starwars" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51oqkfvEwZL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="starwars"></img>
<img class="review-img" id="twilight" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41K99+cInvL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="twilight"></img>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, You can retrieved the selected values of your {genre} and {ratings} options using the `val` method:

```
var sSelectedGenre = $('select[name="genre"]').val().toLowerCase(); // lower case the text after getting its selected value
var sSelectedRating = $('select[name="rating"]').val().toLowerCase();
```

Then each of your  tags must a certain {genre} and {ratings} (e.g data_genre="action" data_rating="6")

```
<img class="review-img" id="kiterunner" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51MtGFNeYjL._AC_US320_QL65_.jpg" alt="kiterunner" data_genre="action" data_rating="6" />
```

This would serve as your 'property keys' to map those conditions.
In iterating, You can loop each or use $.each: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Then check if each images' property match the values based on the selected value from the [options]

Example:

Genre : Adventure

Rating: +8

```
$('.review-img').each(function() {
    var sDataGenre = $(this).attr('data_genre'); // image's action attribute
    var sDataRating = $(this).attr('data_rating'); // 6

    if (sDataGenre === sSelectedGenre && sDataRating === sSelectedRating) {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

For further guidance, here's a sample jsfiddle to help:
http://jsfiddle.net/yctj37yx/ (you can refactor this code better)

Hope this helps for your case. Though I recommend to have your search filter feature in your server side that manage your database (TSQL / SQL) instead

Comment: This code will not work but if you add only option for example latest

Comment: This is for reference. You can figure out what will you do next if you look up the sample code above and experiment yourself. Again, As @Rounin said, Its up to you if you want a client or server side approach.

Comment: can you explain the different between client or server side approach

Comment: This is quite general. Heres a reference for it. softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches according to the degree of scalability you wish to incorporate:

1) For low level scalability, you can manually add HTML5 `data-*` attributes to each image:

```
data-title="Life of Pi"
data-genre="adventure"
data-published="2001"
data-rating="8"
```

2) For higher level scalability, you can create a series of client-side objects, one representing each book

```
var book = {
    title:"Life of Pi",
    genre:"adventure",
    published: 2001,
    rating: 8
    };
```

3) For a high level of scalability, you can build a server-side database and interrogate it via a query language such as MySQL.

Comment: Can you give an example with js fiddle

Comment: You need to decide whether you are adopting a client-side or a server-side approach. You also need to consider the scale of your project.